# How many customers upgraded from Product A to Product B?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have a "daily changes" table that records when a customer "upgrades" or "downgrades" their membership level. In the table, let's say field 1 is customer ID, field 2 is membership type and field 3 is the date of change.  Customers 123 and ABC each have two rows in the table.  Values in field 1 (ID) are the same, but values in field 2 (TYPE) and 3 (DATE) are different. I'd like to write a SQL query to tell me how many customers "upgraded" from membership type 1 to membership type 2 how many customers "downgraded" from membership type 2 to membership type 1 in any given time frame.

The table also shows other types of changes.  To identify the records with changes in the membership type field, I've created the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM member_detail_daily_changes_new
WHERE customer IN (
    SELECT customer
    FROM member_detail_daily_changes_new
    GROUP BY customer
    HAVING COUNT(distinct member_type_cd) > 1)
```

I'd like to see an end report which tells me:

For Fiscal 2018, 
X,XXX customers moved from Member Type 1 to Member Type 2 and 
X,XXX customers moved from Member Type 2 to Member type 1

Comment: What happens if a customer changes from type 1 to 2 and again to 1 at the same year?

Comment: It's possible.  I do see a few rows where one customer has three or more rows in the table.  I guess in those cases, I'd need to count the change from row one to row 2 and the change from row 2 to row 3 using the date field to indicate the sequence of changes.

Comment: So the same customer will be counted in both categories?

Comment: Good question.  I think I'd want to capture both actions for the same customer.  So yes, he'd be counted once as an upgrade and once as a downgrade.

Comment: If anyone else want's to feel free to use the [DEMO](https://rextester.com/edit/ABV1471) created to mockup an answer!  no need to reinvent the wheel on test data!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good time to use a LEAD() analytical function to look ahead for a given customer's member_Type; compare it to current record and then evaluate if thats an upgrade/downgrade then sum results.
[DEMO](https://rextester.com/ABV1471)

```
CTE AS (SELECT case when lead(Member_Type_Code) over (partition by Customer order by date asc) > member_Type_Code then 1 else 0 end as Upgrade
             , case when lead(Member_Type_Code) over (partition by Customer order by date asc) < member_Type_Code then 1 else 0 end as DownGrade
FROM member_detail_daily_changes_new
WHERE Date between '20190101' and '20190201')

SELECT sum(Upgrade) upgrades, sum(downgrade) downgrades
FROM  CTE
```

Giving us: using my sample data

```
+----+----------+------------+
|    | upgrades | downgrades |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |        3 |          2 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I'm not sure if SQL express on rex tester just doesn't support the sum() on the analytic itself which is why I had to add the CTE or if that's a rule in non-SQL express versions too.

***Some other notes:***

- I let the system implicitly cast the dates in the where clause
- I assume the member_Type_Code itself tells me if it's an upgrade or downgrade which long term probably isn't right.  Say we add membership type 3 and it goes between 1 and 2... now what...  So maybe we need a decimal number outside of the Member_Type_Code so we can handle future memberships and if it's an upgrade/downgrade or a lateral...
- I assumed all upgrades/downgrades are counted and a user can be counted multiple times if membership changed that often in time period desired.
- I assume an upgrade/downgrade can't occur on the same date/time.  Otherwise the sorting for lead may not work right.  (but if it's a timestamp field we shouldn't have an issue)

***So how does this work?***

We use a Common table expression (CTE) to generate the desired evaluations of downgrade/upgrade per customer. This could be done in a derived table as well in-line but I find CTE's easier to read; and then we sum it up.

`Lead(Member_Type_Code) over (partition by customer order by date asc)` does the following

It organizes the data by customer and then sorts it by date in ascending order.

So we end up getting all the same customers records in subsequent rows ordered by date.  Lead(field) then starts on record 1 and Looks ahead to record 2 for the same customer and returns the Member_Type_Code of record 2 on record 1. We then can compare those type codes and determine if an upgrade or downgrade occurred.  We then are able to sum the results of the comparison and provide the desired totals.

And now we have a long winded explanation for a very small query :P

Comment: Will test / try it out and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: I had to make some corrections when I was testing it.  Updated to reflect those changes and provided a sample demo using rextester

Comment: I also added lots of comments to help explain what's going on and assumptions and thoughts on it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `lag()` for this, but you need to be careful about the date filtering.  So, I think you want:

```
SELECT prev_membership_type, membership_type,
       COUNT(*) as num_changes,
       COUNT(DISTINCT member) as num_members
FROM (SELECT mddc.*,
             LAG(mddc.membership_type) OVER (PARTITION BY mddc.customer_id ORDER BY mddc.date) as prev_membership_type
      FROM member_detail_daily_changes_new mddc
     ) mddc
WHERE prev_membership_type <> membership_type AND
      date >= '2018-01-01' AND
      date < '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY membership_type, prev_membership_type;
```

Notes:

- The filtering on `date` needs to occur *after* the calculation of `lag()`.
- This takes into account that members may have a certain type in 2017 and then change to a new type in 2018.
- The date filtering is compatible with indexes.
- Two values are calculated.  One is the overall number of changes.  The other counts each member only once for each type of change.

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation after self joining the table:

```
select 
  2018 fiscal, 
  sum(case when m.member_type_cd > t.member_type_cd then 1 else 0 end) upgrades, 
  sum(case when m.member_type_cd < t.member_type_cd then 1 else 0 end) downgrades 
from member_detail_daily_changes_new m inner join member_detail_daily_changes_new t
on 
  t.customer = m.customer 
  and 
  t.changedate = (
    select max(changedate) from member_detail_daily_changes_new
    where customer = m.customer and changedate < m.changedate
  )
where year(m.changedate) = 2018
```

This will work even if there are more than 2 types of membership level.